How to handle notification quick actions clicks on android on background/killed states
basically the situation is i receive a ( data-only ) remote message and then push a local notification and add actions to it, but when it comes to handling em in background and quit state, i click the actions nothing happens here's the code i call on my index.js

PushNotification.configure({
  onNotification: function (notification) {

    const appState = AppState.currentState;

    if (appState !== 'active') {
      if (!notification.userInteraction) {
        PushNotification.localNotification({
          channelId: '// some chennel id',
          title: notification.data.title,
          message: notification.data.message,
          priority: 'high',
          actions: JSON.parse(notification.data.actions).map(
            (item: any) => item.title,
          ),
          smallIcon: 'ic_notification_icon',
          largeIcon: '',
          bigText: '',
          subText: '',
          bigPictureUrl: '',
          userInfo: notification.data,
        });
      } else {
        const actionIdentifier = notification.action;

        if (!actionIdentifier) return;

        switch (actionIdentifier) {
          case 'YES':
            console.log('YEEEEES');
            break;

          case 'NO':
            console.log('NOOOOP');
            break;

          case 'CHECK':
            console.log('check it')
            // this action should open the app and navigate to a notifs screen
            break;

          default:
            console.log('No actionIdentifier selected', actionIdentifier);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  },
});


when i receive the notification here's what notification param logs

{
  "foreground": false,
  "subText": "",
  "smallIcon": "ic_notification_icon",
  "priority": "high",
  "actions": "[\"YES\",\"NO\",\"CHECK\"]",
  "userInteraction": true,
  "bigText": "",
  "id": "1187834229",
  "category": "userAction",
  "title": "test",
  "largeIcon": "",
  "message": "test test test",
  "channelId": "// some channel id",
  "bigPictureUrl": "",
  "data": {}
}


well, tried everything i found on the internet but nothing worked
